# memory error with heap-sort C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, heapsort

So I have written a heap-sort program in C++ which takes in an array of doubles and the size of the array and then sorts it. The program works however when I attempt to pass it arrays larger then 1000 I get "Bus error: 10" I think this has to do with how memory is being allocated, however I can not seem to find a solution.

```
    #ifndef _HEAPSORT_
    #define _HEAPSORT_

void Heapsort(double arrayToSort[], int sizeOfArray);

void Heapsort(double arrayToSort[], int sizeOfArray)
{

//      Building Heap:
// ==========================

int halfSize = sizeOfArray-1 / 2;

for(int i = halfSize; i >= 0; i--){
    double temp = arrayToSort[i];
    int I1 = i, I2 = i+i;
    do {
        if( I2 < sizeOfArray - 1 && arrayToSort[I2+1] > arrayToSort[I2] ) { I2++; }
        if( arrayToSort[I2] > temp ){
            arrayToSort[I1] = arrayToSort[I2];
            I1 = I2;
            I2 = I1+I1;
        } else {
            I2 = sizeOfArray;
        }
    } while ( I2 < sizeOfArray );
    arrayToSort[I1] = temp;
}

//      Sorting Heap:
// =========================

for(int i = sizeOfArray-1; i >= 2; i--){ // i is the number of still competing elements
    double temp = arrayToSort[i];
    arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[0]; // store top of the heap
    int I1 = 0, I2 = 1;
    do {
        if((I2+1) < i && arrayToSort[I2+1] > arrayToSort[I2] ) { I2++; }
        if(arrayToSort[I2] > temp ){
            arrayToSort[I1] = arrayToSort[I2];
            I1 = I2;
            I2 = I1+I1;
        } else {
            I2 = i;
        }
    } while( I2 < i );
    arrayToSort[I1] = temp;

}

double Temp = arrayToSort[1];
arrayToSort[1] = arrayToSort[0];
arrayToSort[0] = Temp;
}

#endif /* _HEAPSORT_ */
```

Any insight into how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the code where I allocate the memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "heapsort.h"
#include "rmaset.h"
#include "ranmar.h"
#include "common.h"


using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
const int size = 1000;
struct Common block;

rmaset(block);

double array[size];

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    array[i] = ranmar(block);
}

Heapsort(array,size);


return 0;
}
```

This just creates a struct which then gets passed to a function which initializes it and then to another function ranmar which populates it with random numbers. I have checked all other functions thoroughly and am sure that the error is coming from the Heapsort function.

Comment: It may well be to do with how the memory is allocated. Unfortunately you didn't post the code where you allocate the memory. Better to post a complete program if possible.

Comment: See if this helps [Bus error: 10 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716714/bus-error-10-error)

Comment: I'm just declaring an array of a certain size and then passing it to the Heapsort function.

Comment: I think most probably OP is statically allocating memory.And allocating 1000*8 bytes might be too much on OP's platform?

Comment: In this `int halfSize = sizeOfArray-1 / 2;` the right side is evaluated as `sizeOfArray-(1 / 2)`. I think you meant to do `(sizeOfArray-1) / 2` instead.

Comment: Does you code sort correctly when you have less than 1000 numbers? Give us a clue here!

Comment: It all sorts correctly however Blastfurnace was right, it was just an evaluation error. However what I dont understand is why it still sorted correctly with this error in the code and why this caused a memory error with large sizes.

Comment: Nope it shouldn't sort correctly.Not, without the @BlastFurnace fix. You've messed the operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line `int halfSize = sizeOfArray-1 / 2;` the right side is evaluated as `sizeOfArray-(1 / 2)`. The integer division `(1 / 2)` results in `0` so it initializes `halfSize` with the value `sizeOfArray`. You begin the loop off the end of the array.  I think you meant to do `(sizeOfArray-1) / 2` instead.