# Return a pointer of an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

EDIT: the solution is on the bottom of the page maybe. I answered my question with the solution. I hope this helps the others.

I'm having here in linux a little problem. I'm programming a simple port scan but I'm having a problem with the function that takes the arguments.

I will explain on the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//this function handle the arguments.

char* ret[2]= {"NULL","NULL"}; //declaring this in global because of segmention fault?

char** arguments_handle(int argc,char **arg)
{
    if(argc!=5)
    {
        printf("Usage:./file -p PORT-RAGE -h HOST.IP\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //make sure the user type the correct arguments. in this case just -h and -p
    if(strcmp(arg[1],"-p")==0 || strcmp(arg[1],"-h")==0 && strcmp(arg[3],"-p")==0 || strcmp(arg[3],"-h")==0)
    {
        //if in the arguments we got -h or -p run this
        //if is -p
        if(strcmp(arg[1],"-p")==0)
        {
            //take the next argument in this case is the port range and put in our array
            strcpy(ret[0],arg[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(ret[1],arg[2]);
        }
        if(strcmp(arg[3],"-h")==0)
        {
            //now for the -h
            strcpy(ret[1],arg[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(ret[0],arg[4]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char** ipnport;
    ipnport = arguments_handle(argc,argv);
    printf("IP is :%s port range is %s\n",ipnport[0],ipnport[1]);
    //the rest of the code about port scan goes here. I'm just cutting
    return 0x0;
}
```

The problem here is that I can compile right but I got Segmentation fault. I can't see where I'm wrong. I guess it is about something deal with buffer or stack overflow.

So what I'm doing here in this function is taking the argv and sending it to arguments_handle function.
What that does is see where is the arguments "-p" and "-h" and "store" that in the right order in an array of char.
Like this char:
"char pointer to this array that contains an array of chars"

```
                    pointer     pointer    pointer
pointer to this-> ["firstarg","secondarg","etc"]
```

In that case, the "pointer pointer pointer" will be the first char of the string.

Summarizing: I want to make a string array and return that from arguments_handle to the main's function.

Any ideas? :)

Sincerely,

int3

Comment: You're accessing `ret` beyond the bounds of the array resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: I think your strcpy is the problem. Look at the answer posted by [Mysticial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716714/bus-error-10-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not allocating the correct memory space for the strings you getting from the command line.

```
char* ret[2]= {"NULL","NULL"};
```

This creates an array with two strings of size 4 + end character ('\0'). Is this what you wanted? Or you want to create two `NULL` pointers. 
What happens if the size of the input string is bigger than 4? You might access a wrong memory which causes a segmentation fault. In addition, you should not use  `strcpy` or `strcmp` but `strncpy` and `strncmp`.

The code should be change as follows :

```
    char * ret[2];

    if(strncmp(arg[3],"-h", 3)==0)
    {   
        string_size = strlen(arg[4]) + 1; 
        ret[1]= malloc(sting_size); 
        memset(ret[1], 0, string_size); 
        strncpy(ret[1],arg[4], string_size);
        // or ret[1]=arg[4] as suggested by Roland
    }
```

However, there is not need for writing a parser for input parameters as the function `getopt` does this for you. This is the manual with a good example at the end : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

A quick example for your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define NUMBER_ARGUMENTS 2 
#define IP 1
#define PORT 0

char* ret[NUMBER_ARGUMENTS];  

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt; 

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:h:")) != -1) {
               switch (opt) {
               case 'p':
                    ret[PORT]=optarg; 
                   break;
               case 'h':
                    ret[IP]=optarg; 
                   break;
               default: /* '?' */
                   fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -p PORT -h HOST\n",
                           argv[0]);
                   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               }
    } 
    printf("IP is :%s port range is %s\n",ret[IP],ret[PORT]);
    //the rest of the code about port scan goes here. I'm just cutting
    return 0x0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `getopt`, -1 for `strncpy`. Simply assigning `argv[i]` to a `const char *hostname` and a `const char *portrange` is easier.

Comment: Really? `malloc`? `strlen`? `strncpy`? Skip all that crud and use `std::string`.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I'm programming C not C++. :) there are no namespaces eheh

Comment: @int3 Then don't tag your question C++ if you're expecting a C only answer.

Comment: I tagged both. my mistake.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it is useful. @RolandIllig, yes you are right. That s the easiest solution and I used in my code example. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem!

Thanks a lot Giuseppe Pes!
I'm not used to malloc and memset and stuff.
But that solves the problem. I knew it was trying to put data where it shouldn't :D

Here is my final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//this function handle the arguments.

//well i didnt edit strcpy and strcmp to strncpy yet but I will :D

char* ret[2]; //GLOBAL ofc.

char** arguments_handle(int argc,char **arg)
{
    if(argc!=5)
    {
        printf("Usage:./file -p PORT-RAGE -h HOST.IP\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //make sure the user type the correct arguments. in this case just -h and -p
    if(strcmp(arg[1],"-p")==0 || strcmp(arg[1],"-h")==0 && strcmp(arg[3],"-p")==0 || strcmp(arg[3],"-h")==0)
    {
        //if in the arguments we got -h or -p run this
        //if is -p
        if(strcmp(arg[1],"-p")==0)
        {
            //take the next argument in this case is the port range and put in our array
            strcpy(ret[0],arg[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(ret[1],arg[2]);
        }
        if(strcmp(arg[3],"-h")==0)
        {
            //now for the -h
            strcpy(ret[1],arg[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(ret[0],arg[4]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //tested on windows we need to put a cast before malloc
    //in linux it works fine on my raspberrypi !! :D
    ret[0] = (char*)malloc(20); //some compilers maybe will throw here an error
    ret[1] = (char*)malloc(20); //because malloc returns a void pointer and ret is a char*

    memset(ret[0],0,20);
    memset(ret[1],0,20);

    char** ipnport;
    ipnport = arguments_handle(argc,argv);
    printf("IP is :%s port range is %s\n",ipnport[1],ipnport[0]);
    //the rest of the code about port scan goes here. I'm just cutting
    return 0x0;
}
```

Thanks again and I hope this code will help some other people seeing this post :)

Sincerely,

int3