# Memory allocation for a string

Tags: c, printf, malloc

I am getting `Bus error: 10` (on run time) just by running the following code:

```
char *x;
char *y = "the quick";
sprintf(x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
```

[Looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716714/what-is-the-meaning-of-bus-error-10-in-c) I have seen a few posts, and the problem seems to be that I am trying to modify a string literal, but in the above code, I think, I am not.
Also, if I try to allocate some memory to `x` using `malloc` everything works, also if I allocate less memory than the one needed to store the whole string, it works even if I allocate `0`.

```
char *x = malloc(0);
char *y = "the quick";
sprintf(x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
printf("%s\n", x); // the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Also I understand this is somehow related to memory allocation, but i'd like to specify `x` without telling the compiler how much memory it will take, since `y` may be a veeeeery long string, or even a number...

How should I do what I am trying to do, just using char pointers (and not arrays of chars), and without having to know the final length of `x`, e.g. without having to calculate the max size of `x` and then memory allocating it?

Comment: Overwriting unallocated memory results in undefined behaviour.. _"Undefined behaviour"_ includes _"apparently working fine"_.

Comment: `char *y = "the quick";` assigns the string-literal to the pointer `y` -- there are no attempts to modify. `char *x = malloc(0);` invokes undefined behavior as the size to allocate must be greater than `0`. You have no validly allocated memory when you attempt `sprintf(x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);` BOOM SegFault.

Comment: @Jabberwocky How should I join that two strings together without using array of chars or specifying the final size of `x`?

Comment: @Giuppox see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `x` does not point to a valid block of memory after your attempt to allocate with `0`. To successfully join both strings into a newly allocated block, you need to know the total number of characters needed to hold both. A convenient way to get the total is to use:

```
snprintf (NULL, 0, "format-string", vars, ...);
```

which will return the total number of characters needed for the combined string. You then allocate `total + 1` to provide space for the nul-terminating character. You can do that with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    
    char *x;
    char *y = "the quick";
    
    /* use snprintf (NULL, 0, "format", vars...) to get no. of chars needed */
    size_t needed = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
    
    x = malloc (needed + 1);    /* allocate for x, +1 for the nul-terminating char */
    if (!x) {                   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-x");
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* now use sprintf to joins string in newly allocated block */
    sprintf (x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
    
    puts (x);       /* output result */
    free (x);       /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/snprintfNULL0
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Memory Use/Error Check***

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/snprintfNULL0
==31830== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31830== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31830== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31830== Command: ./bin/snprintfNULL0
==31830==
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
==31830==
==31830== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31830==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31830==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,069 bytes allocated
==31830==
==31830== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31830==
==31830== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31830== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look this over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: hi thanks for you answer. In you example, if malloc fails and x is NULL, shouldn't we free the it?

Comment: No need, if `malloc()` fails, nothing was allocated so there is nothing to free `:)`

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` stores the string including the conversions specified into the array pionted to by its first argument. It is the programmers responsibility to pass an array large enough for the converted string, including its final terminator.

In your first example, writing through an uninitialized pointer has undefined behavior, which may result in a crash as you observe.

In the second example, `malloc(0)` may return `NULL` or a valid pointer that should not be used for writing as it points to an array of size `0`. In both cases, `sprintf` invokes undefined behavior, which in this case for your machine at the time you tested produced the expected behavior because the invalid writes went undetected, but may have caused side effects only visible later.

Here is a modified version:

```
char x[80];
char *y = "the quick";
sprintf(x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
printf("%s\n", x); // the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

It is much safer to use `snprintf()` and pass the actual size of the destination array to avoid undefined behavior if it happens to be too short. The string will be truncated to fit in the array but the return value will the total number of bytes generated by the conversion:

```
char x[25];
char *y = "the quick";
int n = snprintf(x, sizeof x, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
printf("%s, needs %d bytes\n", x, n + 1); // the quick brown fox jump, needs 44 bytes
```

You can determine the required size by calling `snprintf` with a null pointer and a zero size:

```
size_t minimum_size = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", y);
```

Some systems also have a alternative function [`asprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) that allocates the required memory automatically, but this is a GNU extension that is not widely available.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is, you can't do it without calculating the final size of the buffer.

The good news is that you can let [snprintf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) do the calculation for you.

```
const char *y = "the quick";
const char *fmt = "%s brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

int sizeneeded = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, y) + 1;
char *dest = malloc(sizeneeded);
snprintf(dest, sizeneeded, fmt, y);
printf("%s\n", dest); // the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Disclaimer: the return value of `malloc` is not checked for `NULL` here for brevity.

Comment: maybe it is my machine's problem. But compiling your code with gcc doesn't print the last character of the expected sentence (`the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy do`, without the `g`)

Comment: @Giuppox no, it's my code. It should be `snprintf(dest, sizeneeded + 1, fmt, y);` instead of `snprintf(dest, sizeneeded, fmt, y);`. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and the problem seems to be that I am trying to modify a string literal, but in the above code, I think, I am not.

Correct, you are not modifying ant string literal. `y` is pointing to a string literal but there is no code doing modifications to the string through `y`.

The problem (in first code snippet) is that `x` is uninitialized.

That problem is solved by the `malloc` but a new problem arise. As you write, you allocate too little memory.

> ... and the problem seems to be that I am trying to modify a string literal, but in the above code, I think, I am not.

Now how can that be?

What happens is that you write to memory outside the array (out-of-bounds access). The C standard defines that as "undefined behavior".

"undefined behavior" means that **anything** may happen. For instance, the program is allowed to crash. But the program may also (appear to) work just like you expected. And that happened to you... your code is wrong - has undefined behavior - but by luck (or rather unluck) it just appeared to work.